# convert string 3pm to 15 using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a string 3pm and i want to convert it to HH using moment.js ?
How can I possibly do that.
I need it because the actual date was 10-03-2018 3pm-4pm ; I split this to only get 3pm and now I need this 3pm in 'HH' that is 15.

Comment: Is using momentJS a requirement ?

Comment: no, it is not required. I thought momentjs would help.

Comment: yes, momentjs will make it simple - have you read the documentation and actually tried anything, or are you waiting on a code monkey to do all the work for you? (oh, you owe two bananas now)

Comment: @JaromandaX  **i tried this**
Code:

var time = deliverytime.split(" ")[1];

    console.log(time.substring(0,3));

    let timeinAMPM = time.substring(0,3);

    let newHour = moment(timeinAMPM).format("HH");

    console.log(newHour); 

and many others they dint work do i posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with moment :

```js
var time24 = moment("3PM", ["hA"]).format("HH:mm");

console.log(time24);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is using moment a requirement?  If you've already split the string just do it yourself, something like:

```
'3pm'.replace(
  /(\d+)([ap]m)?/,
  (match, digits, ampm) => +digits + (ampm === "pm" ? 12 : 0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the document

```
H HH    0..23   Hours (24 hour time)
h hh    1..12   Hours (12 hour time used with a A.)
```

Eg :

- moment().format('HH'): time in 24 hrs format
- ment().format('hh'): time in 12 hrs format